# get the most ordered package using two database tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the count of all packages ordered for the whole week and get the package_id of the one with the highest frequency and also has the status='active' in my package table

these are my database tables

```
sales
+------------+------------------+
| package_id |    datesales     |
+------------+------------------+
|        1   |    timestamp     |
|        2   |    timestamp     |
|        1   |    timestamp     |
|        1   |    timestamp     |
|        2   |    timestamp     |
|        2   |    timestamp     |
|        3   |    timestamp     |
+------------+------------------+
```

```
packages
+------------+------------------+
| package_id |     status       |
+------------+------------------+
|      1     |      inactive    |
|      2     |      active      |
|      3     |      active      |
+------------+------------------+
```

I tried using this sql but I'm not really good with aggregation

```
SELECT count(product_id) as product_id from i.sales
where [i dunno how to put the sql for package table here]
      i.date(datesales) <= curdate() and
      i.date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by product_id
```

with the above example in sales table, since I have 3 counts of package_id=1 and also 3 counts of package_id=2,

I want to get the id for package_id=2 since it is the highest frequency of orders and it has the status='active' in my package table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you basically want `order by` and `limit` and `join`:

```
select package_id, count(*) as cnt
from sales i join
     packages p
     using (package_id)
where -- i.date(i.datesales) <= curdate() and   -- I doubt you have future start dates
      i.datesales >= curdate() - interval 6 day and
      p.status = 'active'
group by package_id 
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52be16a4611a8d45c69da1bc44d6a81f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it returns the count with '8' when i only have 2 entries in the sales table and 4 entries on my package table

Comment: @reveberces . . . It does not return a count of 8.  I added a db<>fiddle.  It returns a count of 3.

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake on my part, when I created the package_id column I entered it with the same ids so it was reading 4packages as 1 and multiplying it by my 2entries on the sales. sorry. and thank you. great help!